# cutting column from file in java

Tags: java

I've searched and can't find my question.
I've saved file with linux output ls -l which content is:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 usr usr 4096 Jan 20 17:49 file1
drwxrwxr-x  4 usr usr 4096 Jan 20 18:00 file2
drwx------  2 usr usr 4096 Feb  3 08:48 catalog1
```

And I want to leave for example only eighth column with hour, and cut off rest of it. What should I do? I'm very beginner with java and programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to match the timestamp (since it's guaranteed that a time-like value will not appear in any of the other fields).  Something like:

```
// Populate this with the output of the ls -l command
String input;

// Create a regular expression pattern to match.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}:\\d{2}");

// Create a matcher for this pattern on the input string.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

// Try to find instances of the given regular expression in the input string.    
while (matcher.find()){
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

---

To retrieve any arbitrary column, you can opt to write a regular expression for whichever column you're trying to retrieve, or you may wish to just split each row on the space character, then select by index.  For example, to get all of the filesizes:

```
String input;

String[] inputLines = input.split("\n");
for (String inputLine : inputLines) {
  String[] columns = inputLine.split(" ");
  System.out.println(columns[4]); // Where 4 indicates the filesize column
}
```

Comment: I've write time for example, I mean that I want to leave one column (which I will choose), time was given for example.

Comment: See my updated answer for information regarding retrieving an arbitrary column.

Comment: Just remember, file name may contain almost anything, including spaces, so 9th column extends until end of line and should not be split.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to extract out the exact information that you are looking for. Try the following code:

```
String value =  "drwxr-xr-x  2 usr usr 4096 Jan 20 17:49 file1\n"+
                "drwxrwxr-x  4 usr usr 4096 Jan 20 18:00 file2\n"+
                "drwx------  2 usr usr 4096 Feb  3 08:48 catalog1";
StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer(10);
StringTokenizer sTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(value,"\n");
while (sTokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String sValue = sTokenizer.nextToken();
    StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(sValue," ");
    int counter = 0;
    while (sToken.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        String token = sToken.nextToken();
        counter++;
        if (counter == 8)//8 is the column that you want to leave.
        {
            sBuffer.append(token+"\n");
            break;
        }
    }           
}
System.out.println(sBuffer.toString());
```

Comment: Thank You, this is exactly what I need!
It's works well, now I must only study line by line how it works ;)